# Promise.all() Never fires when all promises resolved

Tags: javascript, promise, resolve

I have the following code that loops through a list of tables asynchronously, executing each query for each table sequentially. I do know that all of the `dbTableQueryPromises` promises resolve, due to the delayed `console.log`'s output, but the `promise.all` never fires. I only have one table right now `users`. Code and output is below.

```
const dropAllDatabaseTables = () => {
  // tableRequiredList is an object that contains a list of SQL queries, among other things not important to the issue.
  const errorList = [
    'test'
  ];

  return new Promise((allQueriesResolve, allQueriesReject) => {
    const dbTableQueryPromises = tableRequiredList.map((databaseTable) => {
     return new Promise((tableResolve, tableReject) => {
        const dbQueries = databaseTable.table.dropTableQuery;

        dbQueries.reduce((previousPromise, dbTableQuery) => {
          return previousPromise.then(() => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              Logger.info(`Query (${databaseTable.name}): ${dbTableQuery}`);
              dbConn.query(dbTableQuery, function(err, results, fields) {
                if (err) {
                  Logger.error(`Exec error '${databaseTable.name}'. Error reported: ${err}`);
                  errorList.push({ err, dbTableQuery });
                  reject(err);
                  return null;
                }
                resolve({ results, fields });
              });
            });
          }).catch((err) => {
            Logger.error(`Exec error '${databaseTable.name}'. Error reported: ${err}`);
          });
        }, Promise.resolve()).then(() => {
          Logger.info(`Table Drop Completed: ${databaseTable.name}`);
          tableResolve(errorList);
        }).catch((err) => {
          Logger.error(`Exec loop error '${databaseTable.name}'. Error reported: ${err}`);
          tableResolve(errorList);
        });
      });
    });

    console.log(1111, dbTableQueryPromises) // debug code
    setTimeout(() => { // debug code
      console.log(2222, dbTableQueryPromises) // debug code
    }, 1000) // debug code
    Promise.all(dbTableQueryPromises, (results) => {
      console.log(3333, dbTableQueryPromises) // debug code
      Logger.info(`All tables dropped.`);
      allQueriesResolve(results);
    });
  });
};
```

Output:

```
1111 [ Promise { <pending> } ]
info: Query (users.js): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
info: Table Drop Completed: users.js
2222 [ Promise { [ 'test' ] } ]
```

Comment: This is ridiculously complicated code to read because it's a mixture of promises and plain callbacks.  Promisify all your async functions OUTSIDE the main code use.  Then, write your control flow using only asynchronous functions that return promises with no plain callbacks in sight.  Then, of course, you can also reuse the promisified functions.  But, in your case, you can probably just use the built-in promise interface to your database in the first place.

Comment: @jfriend00 I totally agree with you. The code is going to be refactored. It's just for prototyping right now.

Comment: Kind of the point is that you shouldn't even mix promises and plain callbacks in the same control flow at all even with prototyping.  In this case, your database has a promise interface built-in that you can just use if you use the right version of the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Promise.all` is Promise-based, not callback-based. It accepts only a single parameter: the array of Promises to wait for. It then returns a Promise that resolves when all Promises in that array have resolved (or, it rejects as soon as one of those Promises rejects).

Call `.then` on the `Promise.all` instead of trying to pass it a callback:

```
Promise.all(dbTableQueryPromises).then((results) => {
  console.log(3333, dbTableQueryPromises) // debug code
  Logger.info(`All tables dropped.`);
  allQueriesResolve(results);
});
```

Comment: Ahhg, can't believe I missed that. Thank you, that's the reason. I will mark your answer as the answer once SO lets me.